# vb.net - How to concatenate a variable(trimmed) to another variable to complete its variable name

Tags: vb.net

Needed code is something like this:

```
Dim myArray(0) As String
Dim ay As String = "ay"

myArr & ay(0) = "asd"
```

I've tried but did not worked

```
Dim classlist1(0) As String
Dim classlist2(0) As String
Dim classlist3(0) As String
Dim classlist4(0) As String
Dim count As Integer = 0

For _year As Integer = 1 To 4
   ("classlist" & _year)(count) = "hi"
   count += 1
Next
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're even *trying* to do.  You can't assign a value to an *expression*, only to a variable.

Comment: I saw in some post concatenating a control name and a variable, it looks like this, Me.Controls("txtbox" & var). this is what i need but mine is not a control

Comment: controls are objects which have a name, so the `Me.Controls()` version works with them.  You cannot "create" var names in code.  You probably just need an array or List.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you see something like this:

```
Dim classlist1(0) As String
Dim classlist2(0) As String
Dim classlist3(0) As String
' etc.
```

It's an indication that you're using the wrong data structure.  Instead of trying to dynamically build *variable names* (which isn't really possible in a static language, at least not without some really ugly reflection code with a high potential for runtime errors), just use a *collection*.

For example, if you want a collection of strings:

```
Dim classList As New List(Of String)()
```

And if you want a collection of collections of strings:

```
Dim classLists As New List(Of List(Of String))()
```

Then you can reference the nested lists within the parent list.  So to add your first "year" of classes:

```
classLists.Add(new List(Of String))
```

And add a class to that year:

```
classLists(0).Add("some value")
```

---

As you can see, it starts to get a little difficult to keep track of the data structures.  This is where creating custom types and structures becomes very useful.  For example, rather than representing a "year" as a list of strings, create an actual `Year` class.  That class can internally hold a list of strings, and other logic/data.

Comment: apologize to my small brain, but how can I put my 4 arrays namely classlist1 to 4 into a list? so that I can just call classLists(0).add("val") if I want to add in classlist1

Comment: @Shivr: My code is using lists instead of arrays (which you'll find to be a lot easier to use in nested structures like this, particularly when you need to build any complex queries over the structure).  When you want to add a new list to the "list of lists", you do this: `classLists.Add(new List(Of String))`  If you already have a list and want to add it, this: `classLists.Add(existingList)`  This doesn't do anything special, it just creates a "list of lists".  The same rules apply at each level of abstraction.  (Though my last suggestion in the answer still holds, clearly.)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Class` [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Dim classLists As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
'Add items with keys
For _year As Integer = 1 To 4
   classLists.Add(String.Format("classlist{0}",_year), "hi")
Next
```

And you can get value by key later

```
Dim key As String = "classlist2"
Dim value As String = classLists(key)
```